# Symfony2 Doctrine CAST AS DECIMAL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sonata-admin

I use Sonata Admin Bundle in Symfony2 and have a custom filter. In database, column is float (cannot change it). If you type 1333.33 there will be no result.

One solution is to use CAST:

```
CAST( o.price AS DECIMAL) = CAST( 399.99 AS DECIMAL)
```

Query is working just fine in SQL but Doctrine throws an error. So my question is how can use CAST in Doctrine or another reliable solution?

Comment: What is the error? Decimal casting is supported, although I don't see anything immediately wrong.

https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions/blob/master/src/Oro/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/Cast.php

Comment: The error is: Error: Expected known function, got 'CAST'

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine does not provide a `CAST` construct in its DQL (see [this list](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates)).

But for your special case, it should be enough to compare the values multiplyed by 100:

```
o.price * 100 = 399.99 * 100
```